# Powershell Code for List of Distinct Directories

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a file that contains a list such as:

```
tables\mytable1.sql
tables\myTable2.sql
procedures\myProc1.sql
functions\myFunction1.sql
functions\myFunction2.sql
```

From this data (and there will always be a path, and it will always be only one level), I want to retrieve a list of distinct paths (e.g. tables\, procedures\, functions\)

To maybe make it the file that contains this data will already have been read into a list (named $fileList), so the new list ($directoryList ??) can likely derived from it.

I've found reference to the -unique parameter, but I need to look from the start of the line, up to (and including) the '\', of which there will only be one occurrence of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the data on `$fileList`, try this:

```
$directoryList = $fileList | %{ $_.split("\")[0]} | select -unique
```

It will do a foreach (the `%{}`) on the elements of your list, and then split them by the `\` and get you only the first part (in your case, the folder name), after that you use `select -unique` to get just the distinct values.

Alternatively, you could do it like this:

```
$fileList | %{ $_ -replace "\\.*$","" } | select -unique
```

Using `-replace` to remove everything after the `\`.

Also, if for some reason you don't have the values of your textfile on `$fileList` already, you can do so using:

```
$fileList = Get-Content yourFile.txt
```

Comment: How do I work $fileList into this (the source of the original list) and get the results to $directoryList)? Sorry, I'm a beginner, using only basics of PS so far.

Comment: @user2284233 do you need them to include the `\\` as well?

Comment: Okay, I though I could take it from there, but apparently doing something wrong.

Comment: Either way. What I want to do from here is get a list of files in the directories referred to in the final list. Having a little trouble with that.

Comment: @user2284233 you can get help on that as well, but I think that needs to be a separate question...

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213026/powershell-code-to-get-list-of-files

Answer (score 0):

Your file may contain empty lines and more often than not there's an empty line on the last one so this will account for that.

It also has a slightly different regular expression to match from the end of the string that is not a `\` character which will work for paths with multiple levels including your example.

If you have a text file with the following:

```
Z:\Path to somewhere\Files\some file 1.txt
Z:\Path to somewhere\Files\some file 2.txt


tables\mytable1.sql
tables\myTable2.sql
procedures\myProc1.sql
functions\myFunction1.sql
functions\myFunction2.sql
```

With this code which also shows the output after the function:

```
$fileListToProcess = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath(""Desktop""))\list.txt"

Function Get-UniqueDirectoriesFromFile {

  Param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = 'The file where the list of files is.')]
    [string]$LiteralPath
    )

  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath -PathType Leaf) {
    $fileList = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines($LiteralPath)
    return $fileList | %{ $_ -replace '\\[^\\]*$', '' } | ? { $_.trim() -ne "" } | Select -Unique
  }
  else {
    return $null
  }

}

$uniqueDirs = Get-UniqueDirectoriesFromFile -file $fileListToProcess

# Display the results:
$uniqueDirs
# PS>
# Z:\Path to somewhere\Files
# tables
# procedures
# functions
$uniqueDirs.count
# PS> 4
```