# Powershell Code to Get List of Files

Tags: sql, powershell

This question builds on [Powershell Code for List of Distinct Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211582/powershell-code-for-list-of-distinct-directories)

I though I could take it from there, but apparently doing something wrong. What I now want to do is read all files like *.sql in each directory in the $directoryList file into a variable named $files.

Thus if $directoryList contains tables, functions, views and procs, I would read all .sql files (just filename) into the variable. As a clincher, I want to include the path back into the filename (e.g. if views directory contains a file name myview1.sql, then $files would be written with views\myview1.sql). The intent is to make $files look exactly like the contents of $fileList.

I am executing from the root folder, so all paths are relative to that (e.g. views, procs, tables, etc.)

Comment: What have you tried? What errors have your gotten? Please show us the relevant code for what you have already tried.

Comment: At the very least, you need to show some examples of expected output and maybe explain why you don't just capture a `dir` in the first place?

Comment: Not very much yet. Just 'playing around' with stuff that I was trying to get to work, but not coming close. The final intent is to get a list of 'files' from one file (e.g. proc\myproc1.sql) and a list of files in specific folders, and compare the results. I want to generate output (using compare-object) and report differences between the two.

Comment: As can be seen by the link in this post, the directories I want to search is dynamic and derived from the file I initially read. I then want to capture a list of files in those directories.

Comment: "This question builds on..but apparently doing something wrong" says you've made an effort to do something but it isn't working. We're not going to do the building; post your efforts and explain how specifically it's not working, and ask a specific question we can answer. This is not a "Please modify the code from this other question's answer to suit my requirements" site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$files = $directoryList | %{ Get-ChildItem $_ } | 
    ?{ $_.extension -eq ".sql" } | %{ "$($_.Directory.Name)\$($_.Name)" }
```

It gets the children for each item on `$directoryList` and then keeps only the ones with extension `.sql` as you want, then for each result, it concatenates the folder name and the file name. The result should be identical to your original list.

Comment: At C:\Users\dt204111\AppData\Local\Temp\2\887f8c6b-a4f6-4bb6-870d-41cc2f3481c6.ps1:8 char:71
+      ?{ $_.extension -eq .sql" } | %{ "$($_.Directory.Name)\$($_.Name) <<<< " }
is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\....ps1:line:8 char:74
+      ?{ $_.extension -eq .sql" } | %{ "$($_.Directory.Name)\$($_.Name)" } <<<<

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo (missing a `"`, so it was `-eq .sql"` instead of `-eq ".sql"`), I've corrected the answer